# fetch Microsoft bearer token not working from the browser

Tags: javascript, api, graph

I am trying to implement that

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?view=graph-rest-1.0

Its working from node and postman but not the browser

This was copied from postman

```js
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
myHeaders.append("Cookie", "fpc=blabl; stsservicecookie=estsfd; x-ms-gateway-slice=estsfd");

var urlencoded = new URLSearchParams();
urlencoded.append("client_id", "bla-bla");
urlencoded.append("scope", "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default");
urlencoded.append("client_secret", "bla-bla");
urlencoded.append("grant_type", "client_credentials");

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: urlencoded,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://login.microsoftonline.com/blabla/oauth2/v2.0/token", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Any ideas what i should include or omit in the fetch request?

Comment: were you able to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

The code above will not work in the browser. This code above needs to be executed **on the server** (you are using "client secret").

If you want browser-only (SPA) authorization, consider using PKCE authorization flow instead.

Other than that, the code looks okay, there is nothing wrong with it.